# For loop without the second condition, i.e. the boolean check?

Tags: c, loops, for-loop

I have to write a function that calculates the floor of log base 16 of an unsigned int passed in. There are restrictions as to what operators and what constants we are allowed to use, and we can only use specifically `for` loops.

For clarity, we cannot use any conditional statements(if, else, switch ... ). The function prototype is:

```
int floor_log16(unsigned int x);
```

Allowed operators: `++` `--` `=` `&` `|` `~` `^` `<<` `!` `>>`

Allowed constants: `1` `2` `3` `4` `8` `16`

I wrote a version of the program as follows:

```
int floor_log16(unsigned int x) {
    int index=1;
    int count=(1!=1);

    count--;

    for(; index<=x; index<<=4) {
        count++;
    }

    return count;
}
```

which seems to work as desired. However, I realized that based on the later functions and description of the needed functionality we have to write, I noticed that under "allowed operators" sometimes `>` and `<` were listed.

I deduce this implies that since for the `floor_log16` function listed above, we weren't explicitly told to use `>` or `<`, I can only assume that the solution posted above will not be accepted.

This leaves me rather confused because I don't understand how you can possibly have a for loop without a boolean check?

Isn't the whole idea of a loop to iterate while a condition is met?

Comment: For interest sake, you can make an if-statement using a for-loop, so the if-statement restriction is somewhat trivial (similarly for the `else`) - `if (condition) statement;` = `for(;condition;) {statement; break;}`, but I don't suppose you're meant to do that.

Comment: Maybe something like `for(;x;x>>4)` ? which will stop when `x == 0`

Comment: "I don't understand how you can possibly have a for loop without a boolean check?" -- The for loop itself does a boolean check ... it either continues or ends depending on the value of an expression. "Isn't the whole idea of a loop to iterate while a condition is met?" -- No, it's to iterate while the expression is non-zero. This would be clear to you if you were to actually read the documentation rather than philosophizing on "the whole idea" of things. Consider that students with the right intellectual skills will get better grades and get the jobs.

Comment: `int count = (1 != 1)` ... "!=" is not an allowed operator. `index <<= 4` ... also not an allowed operator, but `index = index << 4` is ok.

Comment: I think the allowed operators have been enough to accomplish this task.

Answer (score 5):

Well, first of all, `for`-loop without the boolean check is perfectly fine. For example,

```
for (;;)
```

is a common way of writing

```
while (true)
```

Second, having a `for`-loop with other parts but without boolean check is still useful as you can exit it with `return` or `break`.

And the last thing. There are tons of ways of getting a boolean without using `<` and `>`. For example, you can simply use `i` to check that `i != 0` and so on.

For example if you want to check that `a < b` you can check for `(a - b) < 0` instead. Implementing addition (and hence subtraction) with bitwise operators is a well known interview question (you should really try to do this yourself, it's fun), and checking that your `int` is negative is as easy as looking at its most significant bit.

Comment: After noticing that others are answering the question in terms of your exact task I just want to note, that what I said in the last paragraph is just a general demonstration of power of bitwise operators. That's too complicated for your particular task and it can be solved way easier.

Answer (score 2):

I don't like to spoil your task but consider about `for` condition like 'comparison to 0'. This doesn't require any explicit operator. One of possible way to get it is something like this:

```
// This cycle will end as soon as index is 0.
for (;index; index = (index >> 4))
{
    // ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you XOR any unsigned with itself, it becomes 0.  So `int count=(1!=1);` could be changed to `int count = 1 ^ 1`.

As for the loop condition, Roman's idea of comparison to 0 seems like the most natural way to go.