# For Loop without condition

Tags: c#

I came across this code

```
var i=Array.ConvertAll(Console.ReadLine().Split(),int.Parse);
for(int x=i[0]-i[2],y=i[1]-i[3];;Console.WriteLine((0!=y?0<y--?"S":"N":"")+(0!=x?0<x--?"E":"W":"")));
```

I think I understand `int x=i[0]-i[2],y=i[1]-i[3]` but the part that confuses me is that there is no end condition.  So my question is, how does this loop terminate?

I saw this answer which talks about a endless loop.

[For Loop without condition](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17004500/for-loop-without-the-second-condition-i-e-the-boolean-check)

Comment: I am all for cutting down on variable clutter, however, that is very obtuse code.

Comment: All 3 sections (initializer, condition, iterator) of a loop declaration are optional. This means that `for(;;)` is synonymous with `while(true)`.

Comment: It's an infinite loop. As stated in the answer below, all three sections are optional.
@lrb looks like a "read this code" task copied from some twisted c++ book (similar constructs can be elegant in c++ though imho)

Comment: hmm, I have to look again because the loop is not infinite. Maybe something else triggers its termination.

Comment: @Sergey.quixoticaxis.Ivanov - I understand the operations that are avoided by accessing the array reference and index in the loop as opposed to spelling out the semantics of the operation by defining extra variables, however, if this is not embed code then wft? My 280 GB laptop running more memory than the Apollo space mission says hello.

Comment: @lrb this one is just obtuse. Also every C# snippet like this is often bad, 'cuase C# grammar does not allow some c++ style elegant operations like` while(*p++ = *q++)`

Comment: Wow such hate for my question?  Makes me want to remove it but that would not be fair to PNS

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In programming languages, there are loops which are written to run perpetually, unless some external condition (e.g., an exception, or a user signal) is received. Some times, such "infinite" loops are written by mistake.

The loop in the question appears to be just one more case of an infinite loop, probably written intentionally so.

Comment: hmm, I have to look again because the loop is not infinite.  Mabe something else triggers its termination.

Comment: The code excerpt you published does not show any exit condition, but of course it will be there, if you see it happening. :-)

Answer (score 0):

The loop

```
for(int x=i[0]-i[2],y=i[1]-i[3];;Console.WriteLine((0!=y?0<y--?"S":"N":"")+(0!=x?0<x--?"E":"W":"")));
```

from the question will never come to an end. You can check that by putting something like `Console.WriteLine("Loop finished, yet.")` after it. That line will never be reached.

That you see that the loop regardless comes to an end, may have one of these reasons:

- Depending on the user's input for the ReadLine-statement, initializing the array or accessing it with `int x=i[0]-i[2],y=i[1]-i[3]` will lead to an exception. Then the loop will not be executed.
- Maybe the thread, in which the loop is executed, gets aborted.
- If the loop is executed without aborting the thread or something, the loop variables x and y will eventually both be zero. Then the loop will produce only empty lines. Maybe one misinterprets that as the end. But the loop still goes on. (Both variables x and y will eventually be zero, because in each step they are decreased by 1 if they are not zero. If they start with negative values, they will reach the smallest possible integer value, after that they will reach the highest possible integer value, which is positive. Then they will be decreased normally, until they reach zero. Then they will always stay zero.)

Nevertheless, the loop is infinite. If it gets aborted, the reason of that is definitely not in that loop, only outside.

In my opinion, the iteration part of a for loop is only for changing the loop-variables. One invented the body part of a loop for the other stuff like screen-output or something. Hence that loop above is bad code.